# How to get parent group Product ID from getParentIdsByChild() method of \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped?

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

Currently, I am having an issue with retrieving group parent product_id using PHP external script wich file resides under /pub directory:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require '../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productRepository = 
$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');

$typeGroup = $objectManager->get('\Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped');

//child product_id
$simple_child_associated_to_group_product_id = 13884;
$product = $productRepository->getById($simple_child_associated_to_group_product_id);

//this returns the 
//row_id of the parent not the product_id
$groupParentIds = $typeGroup->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());


//shortens the array by one element and store it to a variable
$groupParentId = array_shift($groupParentIds); 

//display group parent id
echo $groupParentId;
```

> **You can confirm the echoed value is the row_id value of 
>       getParentIdsByChild() using this query in your M2 Database:**

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `row_id` = 'put $groupParentId value here'
```

> **Take note of the entity_id:23526**

[image]
To confirm that the returned value of $groupParentId is truly the parent product of the child simple... you can confirm this by:

> **log-in to your admin panel, go to catalog > products, then search the parent product via ID filter with value of 23526**
>   [image]
>
> **click the row to open the product info. and check the associated simple products in the Grouped Products section.**

Comment: did you try var_dump($groupParentIds) ?

Comment: @Mohitchauhan yes sir I tried and it returns the row_id of a product. I checked the native Magento 2 getParentIdsByChild() method equivalent SQL query: 
**SELECT `catalog_product_link`.`product_id`, `catalog_product_link`.`linked_product_id` FROM `catalog_product_link` WHERE (linked_product_id IN('13884')) AND (link_type_id = 3)**  and confirmed that the  product_id column of the catalog_product_link table is equivalent to the row id of the catalog_product_entity

Comment: So this row_id is actually product_id of group product. now what else you want here ?

Comment: @Mohitchauhan I basically wanted to retrieve the entity_id or product_id of a product given that I already have it's row_id. I already tried loading the product using product repository getById(row_id) however it returns me incorrect data. The product repository expects the id to be entity_id or product_id of a product.

Comment: Didn't get you. you already have product_id as row_id.

Comment: @Mohitchauhan Okay, here's the problem I already have the row_id of a product however this is not the type of id I want. My goal is to get the entity_id of a product. You cannot load a product using it's row_id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91590/discussion-between-eubie-aluad-and-mohit-chauhan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mhitchauhan answered my question by using this line of codes in my PHP external script file:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager 
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection'); 
$connection = $resource->getConnection(); 
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity'); //gives table name with prefix 
//Select Data from table 
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName ." where row_id='$row_id'"; 
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 
var_dump($result);
```